# Order successive points

Tags: python

I have a text file with the coordinates of 100 points belonging to a number of parabolas. Each point is described by a line with the following structure: `X_coordinate`, `Y_coordinate`, `ID`, `next_ID`, `tag`.

`ID` is the line number, and `next_ID` is the ID of the point following the considered one along a certain parabola. Generally, `next_ID != ID + 1`. I want my script to give all the points of a certain parabola the same `tag`; do you have any suggestion on how to do it?

The input file look like

```
23.009   784.343  1  22 
472.844  387.843  2  0
32.899   209.027  3  23
345.283  294.034  4  24
[...]
48.939   778.283  22 35
```

What I want to do is to add a tag column, so to have

```
23.009   784.343  1  22  1 
472.844  387.843  2  0   0
32.899   209.027  3  23  2
345.283  294.034  4  24  3
[...]
48.939   778.283  22 35  1
```

Below you can find the code I come up with. If possible I would like to use a more pythonic solution ;-)

```
for i in range(0, Number_of_lines_in_txt):
    if next_ID[i] != 0:  # I check that the considered point has a following one along
                         # The considered parabola
        if tag[i] == 0:  # If the point is already tagged, we skip it
            tag = tag + 1
            tag[i] = tag
            #  Now we do the same for next_ID: we check if it has a following point, 
            #  We check if it has a tag.
            if next_ID[next_ID[i]] != 0: 
                if tag[next_ID[i]] == 0:
                    tag[next_ID[i]] == tag
                        #  Third iteration
                        if next_ID[next_ID[next_ID[i]]] != 0
                        [...]
```

Comment: Can you explain your logic a little more clearly? What's with all the 0 checking? Do you have any `elif`s? If not, you can roll some of those if statements together. Please give some example input and output

Comment: Hi @AndyG, I am adding more information in the question

Comment: At a glance it looks like you should use the CSV module to read the file ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples ), then use `row[4] == {tag}` to get the data you want, then use `sorted()` sorting on next_ID to put them in order, that will result in a list of all the points for a tag. But, I also don't follow what your code example is doing, and this seems like it would do what you want but not what your code is doing.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: I cannot read `tag` from the file because it is not assigned to the points. I have to do it, so to connect the points belonging to the same parabola.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like what you want to do is create a `Point` class, then create a list of `Point` objects, with some default tag. Finally, you need to perform a depth first search on the list to create tags. Then you'll want to write the `Point`s back out to a file, ideally by writing the `__repr__` function for each `Point`.

Something like (untested, written here in the answer box)

```
class Point():
   tag = 0
   def __init__(self, xCoord, yCoord, id, nextID):
      self.xCoord = xCoord
      self.yCoord = yCoord
      self.id     = id
      self.nextID = nextID
  def __repr__(self):
     return "%f %f %d %d %d" % (xCoord, yCoord, id, nextID, tag)

"""do some file I/O, call readlines() to fill a list named lines"""

pointDictionary = {}

for line in lines:
   col = line.split()
   point = Point(float(col[0]), float(col[1]), int(col[2]), int(col[3]))
   pointDictionary[point] = False #unvisited for our DFS

#DFS
def DFS(nextPoint, pointDict, tag): #DFS from this point, setting all to same tag
   if pointDict[nextPoint] == True:
      return

   pointDict[nextPoint] = True
   nextPoint.tag = tag
   DFS(pointDict[nextPoint.nextID-1], pointDict, tag) #assuming IDs are from 1...n

tag = -1
for point in pointDictionary:
   if pointDictionary[point] == False:
      tag += 1
      DFS(point, pointDictionary, tag)


"""Now some I/O to simply write contents of
   pointDictionary (keys only) to an output file"""
```

*EDIT*: I still don't completely understand your logic for assigning tags. Mine will go through all those points connected via `nextID`s and assign them tags starting from 0. I assume that the points are either ordered such that all points in the parabola can be reached by traversing `nextID`s